# Run gulp task when starting web application inside Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, gulp, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I have ASP.NET Core website which I open in Visual Studio 2019. There I have gulp task `watch` that runs BrowserSync for synchronizing wwwroot changes directly to browser. Right now I have to run watch task from Task Runner Explorer and then start website with CTRL+F5 and well I often forget to do that.

Is there a way to run `gulp watch` when starting the app? If it could also end with the IIS Express process that would be great. I thought maybe something like this

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "gulp watch & IISExpress", // (doesn't work)
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:3000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TaskRunnerExplorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TaskRunnerExplorer) to do that

Task Runner Explorer proivide 4 bindings step

```
Before Build

After Build

Clean

Solution Open
```

You can choose binding step base on you need

Comment: I was approaching it wrong, Solution Open is sufficient for me. Thanks.